# Elasticsearch: Fetch documents where nested documents satisfy criteria

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

Elasticsearch 6.8
Imagine I have the following mapping:

```
    indexes:
        big_box:
            types:
                _doc:
                    dynamic: strict
                    properties:
                        medium_boxes:
                            type: nested
                            include_in_parent: true
                            properties:
                                small_boxes:
                                    type: nested
                                    include_in_parent: true
                                    properties:
                                        id: { type: integer, index: true } 
                                        type: { type: keyword, index: true }
```

I want to fetch all big_box documents where there is at least one medium_box which contains small_box with id:1234 and does not contain small_box with type:"BB".

For example,

1. this big_box must NOT be fetched (has both id:1234 and type:"BB" within the same medium_box):

```
...
"medium_boxes": [
    {
        "small_boxes": [
            {
                "id":1234,
                "type": "AA"
            },
            {
                "id":9999,
                "type": "BB"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

2. This big_box MUST be fetched (has at least one medium_box with id:1234 and no type:"BB"). The fact that there is another medium_box with both id:1234 and type:"BB" is irrelevant in this case.

```
...
"medium_boxes": [
    {
        "small_boxes": [
            {
                "id":1234,
                "type": "AA"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "small_boxes": [
            {
                "id":1234,
                "type": "AA"
            },
            {
                "id":9999,
                "type": "BB"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried something like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "medium_boxes",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must_not": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "medium_boxes.small_boxes.type": "BB"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "term": {
                                            "medium_boxes.small_boxes.id": 1234
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
...
```

It almost works as I want but the problem is that it excludes the document from the second example.